# How to avoid cascading error messages

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, error-handling

I'm trying to design an application error handler that resolves any unhandled exceptions, but there are some cases of undesired behaviour that I can't seem to get around.

`Application_DispatcherUnhandledException` will get called whenever a thread outside of the UI runs into trouble. This will in turn call `App.HandleError` - a static method which will log the issue, display a message to the user, and if something critical is wrong, initiate a shut down of the application.

My main issue seems to be when something in the xaml starts generating Exceptions (such as an exception in a DataTemplate or Routed Event). In most cases, WPF will just keep trying to generate the control that's throwing the exception over and over, resulting in cascading error messages and the App consuming all processor power until it crashes unceremoniously.

[image: Cascading Error Messages]

I thought I had resolved this in the error handler by locking the method, or by returning right away if the method is already in the middle of executing, but this has two problems - the first is that if the same exception keeps occuring, as soon as the user hits "OK" and execution of the ErrorHandler unlocks, it will just pop up again. I need some way of determining if we're in a cascading error state so I can just initiate a shut down of the application.

The other problem is that in the event two or more separate threads produce different errors simultaneously, I certainly don't want any solution that will mistake this for a cascading / unrecoverable error, and I don't want one of the errors to simply get ignored because the other one got there first.

Any ideas? I've considered things like using Interlocked.Increment on an error count, using the lock() statement, and caching the last few errors with time-stamps, but they all seem to have shortcomings.

Here's my latest attempt. I apologize for how thick it is, but I try to handle quite a few unique problems at once.

```
private bool DispatchedErrorsLock = false;
private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    //Prevent Recursion
    e.Handled = true;
    if( DispatchedErrorsLock || ExceptionHandlingTerminated ) return;
    DispatchedErrorsLock = true;

    bool handleSilently = false;
    //Ensures that minor xaml errors don't reset the application
    if( "PresentationFramework,PresentationCore,Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.v4.3".Split(',').Any(s => e.Exception.Source.Contains(s)) )
    {
        handleSilently = true;
    }

    HandleError(e.Exception, "Exception from external thread.", !handleSilently, !handleSilently);
    DispatchedErrorsLock = false;
}

private static int SimultaneousErrors = 0;
private static bool ExceptionHandlingTerminated = false;
public static void HandleError(Exception ex, bool showMsgBox) { HandleError(ex, "", showMsgBox, true); }
public static void HandleError(Exception ex, string extraInfo, bool showMsgBox) { HandleError(ex, extraInfo, showMsgBox, true); }
public static void HandleError(Exception ex, string extraInfo = "", bool showMsgBox = true, bool resetApplication = true)
{
    if( ExceptionHandlingTerminated || App.Current == null ) return;
    Interlocked.Increment(ref SimultaneousErrors); //Thread safe tracking of how many errors are being thrown
    if( SimultaneousErrors > 3 )
    {
        throw new Exception("Too many simultaneous errors have been thrown.");
    }

    try
    {
        if( Thread.CurrentThread != Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Thread )
        {
            //We're not on the UI thread, we must dispatch this call.
            ((App)App.Current).Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action<Exception, string, bool, bool>)
                delegate(Exception _ex, string _extraInfo, bool _showMsgBox, bool _resetApplication)
                {
                    Interlocked.Decrement(ref SimultaneousErrors);
                    HandleError(_ex, _extraInfo, _showMsgBox, _resetApplication);
                }, DispatcherPriority.Background, new object[] { ex, extraInfo, showMsgBox, resetApplication });
            return;
        }

        if( !((App)App.Current).AppStartupComplete )
        {   //We can't handle errors the normal way if the app hasn't started yet.
            extraInfo = "An error occurred before the application could start." + extraInfo;
            throw ex; //Hack: Using throw as a goto statement.
        }

        String ErrMessage = string.Empty;
        if( string.IsNullOrEmpty(extraInfo) && showMsgBox )
            ErrMessage += "An error occurred while processing your request. ";
        else
            ErrMessage += extraInfo;

        if( !showMsgBox && !resetApplication )
            ErrMessage += " This error was handled silently by the application.";

        //Logs an error somewhere.
        ErrorLog.CreateErrorLog(ex, ErrMessage);

        if( showMsgBox )
        {
            ErrMessage += "\nTechnical Details: " + ex.Message;
            Exception innerException = ex.InnerException;
            while( innerException != null )
            {   //Add what is likely the more informative information in the inner exception(s)
                ErrMessage += " | " + ex.InnerException.Message;
                innerException = innerException.InnerException;
            }
        }

        if( resetApplication )
        {
            //Resets all object models to initial state (doesn't seem to help if the UI gets corrupted though)
            ((MUS.App)App.Current).ResetApplication();
        }
        if( showMsgBox )
        {
            //IF the UI is processing a visual tree event (such as IsVisibleChanged), it throws an exception when showing a MessageBox as described here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/44962927-006e-4629-9aa3-100357861442
            //The solution is to dispatch and queue the MessageBox. We must use BeginInvoke() because dispatcher processing is suspended in such cases, so Invoke() would fail..
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ErrMessage, "MUS Application Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                Interlocked.Decrement(ref SimultaneousErrors);
            }, DispatcherPriority.Background);
        }
        else
        {
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref SimultaneousErrors);
        }
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref SimultaneousErrors);
        ExceptionHandlingTerminated = true;
        //A very serious error has occurred, such as the application not loading or a cascading error message, and we must shut down.
        String fatalMessage = String.Concat("An error occurred that the application cannot recover from. The application will have to shut down now.\n\nTechnical Details: ", extraInfo, "\n", e.Message);
        //Try to log the error, but in extreme cases, there's no guarantee logging will work.
        try { ErrorLog.CreateErrorLog(ex, fatalMessage); }
        catch( Exception ) { }
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
        {
            MessageBox.Show(fatalMessage, "Fatal Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Stop);
            if( App.Current != null ) App.Current.Shutdown(1);
        }, DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }
}
```

Comment: They could _at least_ bounce off the boundary like solitaire cards.

Comment: Where to you increment SimultaneousErrors?

Comment: What about simply storing exceptions in a Collection, then displaying a single custom popup containing an `ItemsControl` or `ListBox` bound to the list of exceptions?

Comment: Not sure if this will help in this case but I use it as central way to handle unhandled exceptions  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90866/Unhandled-Exception-Handler-For-WPF-Applications

Comment: @Rachel - Not a bad design idea Rachel, but even then, I need to fix my exception handling to prevent infinitely adding repeating exceptions to the items control until the UI hangs.

Comment: @Blam - look up Interlocked.Increment, and your linked implementation is far too basic, and doesn't take any of the things into account that this implementation does. I can see 2 ways of breaking it already - cascading dispatched error messages from the xaml, and any error spawned from a UI event such as 'IsVisibleChanged' - which prevents MessageBox.Show from being placed on the call stack.

Comment: @Alain It would definitely be best if you could fix the infinite loop, but you could also put a limit on the number of items allowed in the error collection. Once that threshold gets hit, you could do any number of things, like just increase an int counter showing how many other exceptions have occured, or even shut down the application. Once the user clicks OK on the exception popup, it should dismiss those errors and clear the error collection.

Comment: I've attempted to solve the problem using `lock()` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893299/lock-on-static-object-from-within-a-delegate-is-not-working and using `semaphores` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894750/how-can-i-get-the-ui-thread-to-wait-on-a-semaphore-but-process-additional-dispa, but still no dice.

Comment: What about making assumptions based on two criteria: time and source. If the same source produces second unhandled exception in a sufficiently small ammount of time after the first one then we can assume that there likely will be the third exception, the fourth and so on, so we are in case when it is necessary to shutdown application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Rachel, for your helpful input. I've decided to go with storing them in a collection. I haven't gone as far as displaying them in custom popup control, but am simply handling errors in sequence and then popping a new one off the stack (if there are any). If too many errors build up on the stack, then I assume we're in a cascading error situation and I aggregate the errors together in a single message and shut down the app.

```
private static ConcurrentStack<Tuple<DateTime, Exception, String, bool, bool>> ErrorStack = new ConcurrentStack<Tuple<DateTime, Exception, String, bool, bool>>();
private static bool ExceptionHandlingTerminated = false;
private static bool ErrorBeingHandled = false; //Only one Error can be processed at a time

public static void HandleError(Exception ex, bool showMsgBox) { HandleError(ex, "", showMsgBox, true); }
public static void HandleError(Exception ex, string extraInfo, bool showMsgBox) { HandleError(ex, extraInfo, showMsgBox, true); }
public static void HandleError(Exception ex, string extraInfo = "", bool showMsgBox = true, bool resetApplication = true)
{
    if( ExceptionHandlingTerminated || App.Current == null) return;
    if( ErrorBeingHandled )
    {   //Queue up this error, it'll be handled later. Don't bother if we've already queued up more than 10 errors, we're just going to be terminating the application in that case anyway.
        if( ErrorStack.Count < 10 )
            ErrorStack.Push(new Tuple<DateTime, Exception, String, bool, bool>(DateTime.Now, ex, extraInfo, showMsgBox, resetApplication)); //Thread safe tracking of how many simultaneous errors are being thrown
        return;
    }

    ErrorBeingHandled = true;
    try
    {
        if( Thread.CurrentThread != Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Thread )
        {
            ErrorBeingHandled = false;
            Invoke_HandleError( ex, extraInfo, showMsgBox, resetApplication );
            return;
        }
        if( ErrorStack.Count >= 5 )
        {
            ExceptionHandlingTerminated = true;
            Tuple<DateTime, Exception, String, bool, bool> errParams;
            String errQueue = String.Concat(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.ff tt"), ": ", ex.Message, "\n");
            while( ErrorStack.Count > 0 )
            {
                if( ErrorStack.TryPop(out errParams) )
                {
                    errQueue += String.Concat(errParams.Item1.ToString("hh:mm:ss.ff tt"), ": ", errParams.Item2.Message, "\n");
                }
            }
            extraInfo = "Too many simultaneous errors have been thrown in the background:";
            throw new Exception(errQueue);
        }

        if( !((App)App.Current).AppStartupComplete )
        {   //We can't handle errors the normal way if the app hasn't started yet.
            extraInfo = "An error occurred before the application could start." + extraInfo;
            throw ex;
        }

        if( resetApplication )
        {
            ((MUSUI.App)App.Current).ResetApplication();
        }
        if( showMsgBox )
        {
            //(removed)... Prepare Error message

            //IF the UI is processing a visual tree event (such as IsVisibleChanged), it throws an exception when showing a MessageBox as described here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/44962927-006e-4629-9aa3-100357861442
            //The solution is to dispatch and queue the MessageBox. We must use BeginInvoke because dispatcher processing is suspended in such cases.
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action<Exception, String>)delegate(Exception _ex, String _ErrMessage)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(App.Current.MainWindow, _ErrMessage, "MUS Application Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                ErrorHandled(_ex); //Release the block on the HandleError method and handle any additional queued errors.
            }, DispatcherPriority.Background, new object[]{ ex, ErrMessage });
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorHandled(ex);
        }
    }
    catch( Exception terminatingError )
    {
        ExceptionHandlingTerminated = true;
        //A very serious error has occurred, such as the application not loading, and we must shut down.
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action<String>)delegate(String _fatalMessage)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(_fatalMessage, "Fatal Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Stop);
            if( App.Current != null ) App.Current.Shutdown(1);
        }, DispatcherPriority.Background, new object[] { fatalMessage + "\n" + terminatingError.Message });
    }
}

//The set of actions to be performed when error handling is done.
private static void ErrorHandled(Exception ex)
{
    ErrorBeingHandled = false;

    //If other errors have gotten queued up since this one was being handled, or remain, process the next one
    if(ErrorStack.Count > 0)
    {
        if( ExceptionHandlingTerminated || App.Current == null) return;
        Tuple<DateTime, Exception, String, bool, bool> errParams;
        //Pop an error off the queue and deal with it:
        ErrorStack.TryPop(out errParams);
        HandleError(errParams.Item2, errParams.Item3, errParams.Item4, errParams.Item5);
    }
}

//Dispatches a call to HandleError on the UI thread.
private static void Invoke_HandleError(Exception ex, string extraInfo, bool showMsgBox, bool resetApplication)
{
    ((App)App.Current).Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action<Exception, string, bool, bool>)
        delegate(Exception _ex, string _extraInfo, bool _showMsgBox, bool _resetApplication)
        {
            ErrorHandled(_ex); //Release the semaphore taken by the spawning HandleError call
            HandleError(_ex, _extraInfo, _showMsgBox, _resetApplication);
        }, DispatcherPriority.Background, new object[] { ex, extraInfo, showMsgBox, resetApplication });
}
```