# Lock on static object from within a delegate is not working

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

How come this isn't working?

```
private static object Lock_HandleError = new object();
public static void HandleError(Exception ex)
{
    lock( Lock_HandleError )
    {
        //IF the UI is processing a visual tree event (such as IsVisibleChanged), it throws an exception when showing a MessageBox as described here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/44962927-006e-4629-9aa3-100357861442
        //The solution is to dispatch and queue the MessageBox. We must use BeginInvoke because dispatcher processing is suspended in such cases.
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
        {
            lock( Lock_HandleError )
            {
                Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate(){ 
                    HandleError(new Exception("testing purposes only")); 
                }, DispatcherPriority.Background);

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Application Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                //This point is not reached until the user clicks "OK"
            }
        }, DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }
}

public void main()
{
    HandleError(new Exception("The first error"));
}
```

The expected behaviour of the above code is that one error message will appear at a time, and when the user clicks "OK", the on the `Lock_HandleError` object will get released from the dispatched thread, and the next call to HandleError can proceed - but what I'm getting is an infinite cascade of error messages without ever getting to hit "OK".

Why isn't this lock working?

By setting breakpoints at the entry and exit of each lock statement, I can clearly see that the delegate is calling `lock()` and dispatching the a new call to "HandleError" again and then pausing on MessageBox to wait for user input.

Meanwhile, in another thread, that dispatched call to HandleError gets run - but instead of waiting at the lock() statement like it should, it's just blasting through it even though the MessageBox delegate clearly placed a lock and has not yet released it.

Comment: I'm not up to scratch on my multi-threading, but I'm wondering if you could try removing the `lock` within the `BeginInvoke` method?

Comment: Removing the lock doesn't accomplish anything - because the lock acts like it isn't even there as is. While the UI thread is waiting for the user to click "OK" on the message box, it processes additional calls to HandleError() coming from other areas of the application, and I need it to stop and wait.

Comment: I've attempted to solve the problem using semaphores here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894750/how-can-i-get-the-ui-thread-to-wait-on-a-semaphore-but-process-additional-dispa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two part answer:

1. Understand that locks are re-entrant.  When a thread already holds a lock on an object, that thread can take the same lock again and again without blocking.
2. While the first MessageBox is up, the UI thread is still pumping messages, so subsequent (recursive) calls to `HandleError` are being processed on the UI thread (which, because it already holds the lock, can re-enter it).

Comment: So far this is the most complete explanation, because I both expected the MessageBox to block the thread it was running on (according to `2.` it doesn't), and I was expecting locks to block like semaphores regardless of which thread owns it (according to `1.` it doesn't). While my question doesn't explicitly ask for a solution to my problem that does work, only why mine doesn't work, I'd still be interested in knowing if there's an easy fix for this sort of problem.

Answer (score 6):

> Why isn't this lock working?

A thread is allowed to enter a lock statement which it already owns.  In essense, lock doesn't block its own thread.

As such, what's happening is the original thread takes the lock, and then is allowed to add messages to the Dispatcher's Queue.  It can add as many as it wants.

The Dispatcher, when processing, gets the first message, and then calls HandleError.  Since this is running in the dispatcher thread, it's allowed to enter the outer and inner lock, and call HandleError again, recursively adding new messages to the queue in an endless loop.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Clearly lock() is not what I want to use then. How can I achieve what I intended?

Comment: @Alain Why are you calling yourself recursively with BeginInvoke?  That's going to be problematic, as anything that gave you the behavior you were after would effectively dead lock you.

Comment: It's to simulate what happens in practice, which is many different threads experience simultaneous errors, and they all dispatch a call to `HandleError()` on the UI thread - but rather than waiting for one MessageBox to be dismissed before handling the next error, the application cascades all errors simultaneously. If we have a recurring error, this lock not working prevents me from detecting and dealing with an infinite cascade of message boxes.

Comment: @Alain If you take out the call to HandleError from inside the inner lock (your BeginInvoke is calling HandleError AGAIN), then it will just work, without any locks.  The problem is the recursive posting to the dispatcher...

Comment: I don't think you understand - the above code is simply for demonstration purposes. In actuality, it is not the MessageBox delegate dispatching calls to HandleError - it is other threads in the application. The real Error handler simply calls `MessageBox.Show()` wrapped in a `lock()`, wrapped in a Dispatcher, for the reasons indicated in the comments. The application really is generating infinite cascading error messages, it doesn't just work. While the UI thread is waiting for the user to click "OK", it processes additional calls to `HandleError()` and I need it to stop and wait.

Comment: @Alain You can switch your lock over to using a Semaphore (or SemaphoreSlim in .NET 4) - that will avoid the issue you're having: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx

Comment: I gave semaphores a shot but they block the dispatched call to `MessageBox.Show` from ever seeing the light of day. I've posted as a separate question here if you can offer any insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894750/how-can-i-get-the-ui-thread-to-wait-on-a-semaphore-but-process-additional-dispa