# How can I get the UI thread to wait on a semaphore, but process additional dispatcher requests? (like what MessageBox.Show does natively)

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, error-handling, parallel-processing, semaphore

Normally, when the UI thread calls something like `MessageBox.Show()`, the current code execution doesn't continue until the user clicks OK, but the program will continue to run other code dispatched on the UI thread.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891630/how-to-avoid-cascading-error-messages#comment12619378_9891630), I had a problem with too many delegates dispatched on the UI Thread being called at once. I wanted to pause at certain points before continuing execution.

In my new Error handler, I use semaphores to make sure no more than one error is being handled at once. I dispatch a MessageBox to alert the user, and when they click "OK", I release the semaphore, allowing the next error to be processed.

The problem is that it's not behaving as expected. If two dispatched calls to HandleError happen at the same time, the first one Dispatches a call to MessageBox.Show, and the second one blocks the UI Thread. Strangely, the dispatched call to `MessageBox.Show()` never gets executed - the entire Application just hangs - so the semaphore that's supposed to be released when the user clicked "OK" is permanently locked. What is this solution lacking?

```
private static ConcurrentDictionary<Exception, DateTime> QueuedErrors = new ConcurrentDictionary<Exception, DateTime>();
private static Semaphore Lock_HandleError = new Semaphore(1, 1); //Only one Error can be processed at a time
private static void ErrorHandled(Exception ex)
{
    DateTime value;
    QueuedErrors.TryRemove(ex, out value);
    Lock_HandleError.Release();
}

private static bool ExceptionHandlingTerminated = false;
public static void HandleError(Exception ex, string extraInfo = "", bool showMsgBox = true, bool resetApplication = true)
{
    if( ExceptionHandlingTerminated || App.Current == null) return;
    QueuedErrors.TryAdd(ex, DateTime.Now); //Thread safe tracking of how many simultaneous errors are being thrown

    Lock_HandleError.WaitOne(); //This will ensure only one error is processed at a time.

    if( ExceptionHandlingTerminated || App.Current == null )
    {
        ErrorHandled(ex);
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        if( QueuedErrors.Count > 10 )
        {
            ExceptionHandlingTerminated = true;
            throw new Exception("Too many simultaneous errors have been thrown in the background.");
        }

        if( Thread.CurrentThread != Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Thread )
        {
            //We're not on the UI thread, we must dispatch this call.
            ((App)App.Current).Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action<Exception, string, bool, bool>)
                delegate(Exception _ex, string _extraInfo, bool _showMsgBox, bool _resetApplication)
                {
                    ErrorHandled(_ex); //Release the semaphore taken by the spawning HandleError call
                    HandleError(_ex, _extraInfo, _showMsgBox, _resetApplication);
                }, DispatcherPriority.Background, new object[] { ex, extraInfo, showMsgBox, resetApplication });
            return;
        }

        if( showMsgBox )
        {
            //IF the UI is processing a visual tree event (such as IsVisibleChanged), it throws an exception when showing a MessageBox as described here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/44962927-006e-4629-9aa3-100357861442
            //The solution is to dispatch and queue the MessageBox. We must use BeginInvoke because dispatcher processing is suspended in such cases.
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action<Exception, String>)delegate(Exception _ex, String _ErrMessage)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(_ErrMessage, "MUS Application Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                ErrorHandled(_ex); //Release the semaphore taken by the spawning HandleError call
            }, DispatcherPriority.Background, new object[]{ ex, extraInfo });
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorHandled(ex);
        }
    }
    catch( Exception terminatingError )
    {
        ExceptionHandlingTerminated = true;
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action<String>)delegate(String _fatalMessage)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(_fatalMessage, "Fatal Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Stop);
            if( App.Current != null ) App.Current.Shutdown(1);
        }, DispatcherPriority.Background, new object[] { fatalMessage });
        ErrorHandled(ex); //Release the semaphore taken by this HandleError call which will allow all other queued HandleError calls to continue and check the ExceptionHandlingTerminated flag.
    }
}
```

Don't worry about the odd missing message string, I cut a lot of details out to make the pattern clearer.

Comment: Did you try it with different values of `DispatcherPriority`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the behavior you are looking for is for each message box to wait in turn until the previous message box has been cleared, you want a pattern like this:

1. The event source queues the message in a blocking queue
2. The event source invokes a delegate on a background thread to "Process the Queue"
3. The "Process the Queue" delegate takes a lock (as you have done), dequeues a message, and Invokes (synchronously) to the UI thread to show the message.  Then it loops, doing the same thing until the queue is emtpy.

So something like this (untested code ahead):

```
private static ConcurrentQueue<Tuple<Exception, DateTime>> QueuedErrors = new ConcurrentQueue<Tuple<Exception, DateTime>>();
private static Object Lock_HandleError = new Object();
public static void HandleError(Exception ex, string extraInfo = "", bool showMsgBox = true, bool resetApplication = true)
{
    QueuedErrors.Enqueue(new Tuple<Exception, String>(ex, DateTime.Now));
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(()=>((App)App.Current).Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)
            () => {
                lock (Lock_HandleError)
                    Tuple<Exception, DateTime> currentEx;
                    while (QueuedErrors.TryDequeue(out currentEx))
                        MessageBox.Show(
                           currentEx.Item1, // The exception
                           "MUS Application Error", 
                           MessageBoxButton.OK, 
                           MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }))
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable input. I couldn't quite use your solution, as handling the error requires some complex action to be taken, which had to happen on the UI thread, but you certainly let me to the answer I used, so points for you. My solution is below.

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to go with storing them in a collection as suggested. I am simply handling errors in sequence and then popping a new one off the stack (if there are any). If too many errors build up on the stack, then I assume we're in a cascading error situation and I aggregate the errors together in a single message and shut down the app.

```
private static ConcurrentStack<Tuple<DateTime, Exception, String, bool, bool>> ErrorStack = new ConcurrentStack<Tuple<DateTime, Exception, String, bool, bool>>();
private static bool ExceptionHandlingTerminated = false;
private static bool ErrorBeingHandled = false; //Only one Error can be processed at a time

public static void HandleError(Exception ex, bool showMsgBox) { HandleError(ex, "", showMsgBox, true); }
public static void HandleError(Exception ex, string extraInfo, bool showMsgBox) { HandleError(ex, extraInfo, showMsgBox, true); }
public static void HandleError(Exception ex, string extraInfo = "", bool showMsgBox = true, bool resetApplication = true)
{
    if( ExceptionHandlingTerminated || App.Current == null) return;
    if( ErrorBeingHandled )
    {   //Queue up this error, it'll be handled later. Don't bother if we've already queued up more than 10 errors, we're just going to be terminating the application in that case anyway.
        if( ErrorStack.Count < 10 )
            ErrorStack.Push(new Tuple<DateTime, Exception, String, bool, bool>(DateTime.Now, ex, extraInfo, showMsgBox, resetApplication)); //Thread safe tracking of how many simultaneous errors are being thrown
        return;
    }

    ErrorBeingHandled = true;
    try
    {
        if( Thread.CurrentThread != Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Thread )
        {
            ErrorBeingHandled = false;
            Invoke_HandleError( ex, extraInfo, showMsgBox, resetApplication );
            return;
        }
        if( ErrorStack.Count >= 5 )
        {
            ExceptionHandlingTerminated = true;
            Tuple<DateTime, Exception, String, bool, bool> errParams;
            String errQueue = String.Concat(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.ff tt"), ": ", ex.Message, "\n");
            while( ErrorStack.Count > 0 )
            {
                if( ErrorStack.TryPop(out errParams) )
                {
                    errQueue += String.Concat(errParams.Item1.ToString("hh:mm:ss.ff tt"), ": ", errParams.Item2.Message, "\n");
                }
            }
            extraInfo = "Too many simultaneous errors have been thrown in the background:";
            throw new Exception(errQueue);
        }

        if( !((App)App.Current).AppStartupComplete )
        {   //We can't handle errors the normal way if the app hasn't started yet.
            extraInfo = "An error occurred before the application could start." + extraInfo;
            throw ex;
        }

        if( resetApplication )
        {
            ((MUSUI.App)App.Current).ResetApplication();
        }
        if( showMsgBox )
        {
            //(removed)... Prepare Error message

            //IF the UI is processing a visual tree event (such as IsVisibleChanged), it throws an exception when showing a MessageBox as described here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/44962927-006e-4629-9aa3-100357861442
            //The solution is to dispatch and queue the MessageBox. We must use BeginInvoke because dispatcher processing is suspended in such cases.
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action<Exception, String>)delegate(Exception _ex, String _ErrMessage)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(App.Current.MainWindow, _ErrMessage, "MUS Application Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                ErrorHandled(_ex); //Release the block on the HandleError method and handle any additional queued errors.
            }, DispatcherPriority.Background, new object[]{ ex, ErrMessage });
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorHandled(ex);
        }
    }
    catch( Exception terminatingError )
    {
        ExceptionHandlingTerminated = true;
        //A very serious error has occurred, such as the application not loading, and we must shut down.
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action<String>)delegate(String _fatalMessage)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(_fatalMessage, "Fatal Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Stop);
            if( App.Current != null ) App.Current.Shutdown(1);
        }, DispatcherPriority.Background, new object[] { fatalMessage + "\n" + terminatingError.Message });
    }
}

//The set of actions to be performed when error handling is done.
private static void ErrorHandled(Exception ex)
{
    ErrorBeingHandled = false;

    //If other errors have gotten queued up since this one was being handled, or remain, process the next one
    if(ErrorStack.Count > 0)
    {
        if( ExceptionHandlingTerminated || App.Current == null) return;
        Tuple<DateTime, Exception, String, bool, bool> errParams;
        //Pop an error off the queue and deal with it:
        ErrorStack.TryPop(out errParams);
        HandleError(errParams.Item2, errParams.Item3, errParams.Item4, errParams.Item5);
    }
}

//Dispatches a call to HandleError on the UI thread.
private static void Invoke_HandleError(Exception ex, string extraInfo, bool showMsgBox, bool resetApplication)
{
    ((App)App.Current).Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action<Exception, string, bool, bool>)
        delegate(Exception _ex, string _extraInfo, bool _showMsgBox, bool _resetApplication)
        {
            ErrorHandled(_ex); //Release the semaphore taken by the spawning HandleError call
            HandleError(_ex, _extraInfo, _showMsgBox, _resetApplication);
        }, DispatcherPriority.Background, new object[] { ex, extraInfo, showMsgBox, resetApplication });
}
```